# findOne is not a function while testing using mocha

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, mocha.js, chai

I was testing my 'user' code with mocha and chai, But I keep getting this error. The index.js file which creates models is auto build and was working fine. Then I tried adding tests using mocha and couldn't figure out the reason.

[image: error]

my test folders :

test/user/user_dbtest:

```js
const {expect}=require('chai')
const{usernameExists}=require('../../services/user/user_db')

describe('user db tests',()=>{
 it('check whether username alreddy exists',async()=>{
  const check=await usernameExists('')
  expect(check).to.be.false
  expect(check===null).to.be.false
  expect(check===undefined).to.be.false
 });
});
```

services/user/user_db :

```js
const db=require('../../models/index.js')
async function usernameExists(username){
 const user= await db.user.findOne({
  where:{username}
 });
 if(user) return user
 return false
}
module.exports={usernameExists}
```

models/index.js :

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const config = require('../config/config');
const db = {};
console.log(config)

const sequelize=new Sequelize(config.db.database,config.db.username,config.db.password,{
  dialect:'mysql',
  host:config.db.host
})

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

//ASSOCIATIONS
db.book_belongs_to.belongsTo(db.user)
db.book_belongs_to.belongsTo(db.book)
db.book_bought_by.belongsTo(db.user)
db.book_bought_by.belongsTo(db.book)


sequelize
 .authenticate()
 .then(()=>{
   console.log("connected");
 })
 .catch(err=>{
   console.error(err);
 });

module.exports = db;
```

models/user.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports=(sequelize,Datatypes)=>{
 return sequelize.define('user',{
 username:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
  allowNull:false
 },
 firstname:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
  allowNull:false
 },
 middlename:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
 },
 lastname:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
  allowNull:false
 },
 email:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
  allowNull:false,
  isEmail:true
 },
 password:{
  type:Datatypes.STRING,
  allowNull:false
 }},{
  timestamps:false,
  freezeTableName:true
 })
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You should use a stub/mock library such [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/) to mock `db.user.findOne` method.

E.g.

`user_db.js`:

```js
const db = require('./index.js');

async function usernameExists(username) {
  const user = await db.user.findOne({
    where: { username },
  });
  if (user) return user;
  return false;
}

module.exports = { usernameExists };
```

`index.js`:

```js
// simulate sequelize db
const db = {
  user: {
    findOne() {},
  },
};

module.exports = db;
```

Because we are testing the service layer, the model layer doesn't matter(We stub and mock the models). So, there is no model layer in this example.

`user_db.test.js`:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { usernameExists } = require('./user_db');
const db = require('./index.js');

describe('user db tests', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should return non-existed user', async () => {
    sinon.stub(db.user, 'findOne').resolves(false);
    const check = await usernameExists('');
    expect(check).to.be.false;
    expect(check === null).to.be.false;
    expect(check === undefined).to.be.false;
  });

  it('should return existed user', async () => {
    const fakeUser = { username: 'anna' };
    sinon.stub(db.user, 'findOne').resolves(fakeUser);
    const check = await usernameExists('');
    expect(check).to.be.deep.equal({ username: 'anna' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  user db tests
    ✓ should return non-existed user
    ✓ should return existed user


  2 passing (27ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 index.js   |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 user_db.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/61695519